# How to send the iteration value as a param to lambda function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I build a drop-down with check boxes at Tkinter,
I tried to initialize the checkboxes in loop when I iterate over elements and for every checkbox i want different  `lambda` function which use the element that I get in the specific iteration.

```
  mb = Menubutton(self, text="Select", elief=RAISED)
  mb.menu = Menu(mb,tearoff = 0)
  mb["menu"] = mb.menu
  for elem in self.files:
      mb.menu.add(checkbutton(label = elem, variable = elem, command=lambda: print(elem)))
```

The output that I got is a empty string.

Comment: `command=lambda i=elem: print(i)`

Comment: Please provide a complete code-sample of what you've come up with so far. It's very hard for us to be of assistance otherwise.